# c++ find implicit type conversion in the expression

Tags: c++, type-conversion, implicit-conversion, signedness

For the below expression:-

```
int main()
{
    unsigned ui = 1;
    float fval = 2.5;
    cout << sizeof(ui) << endl << sizeof(fval) << endl;
    cout << typeid(ui+fval).name();
}
```

we get the following output:-

```
4
4
f
```

It seems that ui+fval is a float.

However, given that both float and unsigned int are 4 bytes, and that not all of the unsigned int values can fit inside a float, shouldn't fval be converted to unsigned int?

Comment: The reverse is also true, not all `float` values fit in an `unsigned int`.

Comment: where did you get that from? See here for the actual rules: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Conversions

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rules for arithmetic operators are actually slightly different than the rules for general function overload resolution.

From cppreference on [arithmetic operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic):

> **Conversions**
>
> If the operand passed to an arithmetic operator is integral or unscoped enumeration type, then before any other action (but after lvalue-to-rvalue conversion, if applicable), the operand undergoes integral promotion. If an operand has array or function type, array-to-pointer and function-to-pointer conversions are applied.
>
> For the binary operators (except shifts), if the promoted operands have different types, additional set of implicit conversions is applied, known as *usual arithmetic conversions* with the goal to produce the *common type* (also accessible via the `std::common_type` type trait). If, prior to any integral promotion, one operand is of enumeration type and the other operand is of a floating-point type or a different enumeration type, this behavior is deprecated. (since C++20)
>
> - If either operand has scoped enumeration type, no conversion is performed: the other operand and the return type must have the same type
> - Otherwise, if either operand is `long double`, the other operand is converted to `long double`
> - Otherwise, if either operand is `double`, the other operand is converted to `double`
> - Otherwise, if either operand is `float`, the other operand is converted to `float`
>
> [snip]

So, quite explicitly, when we're doing `unsigned + float`, the `unsigned` gets converted to a `float`. It's the first rule that applies, so we follow it.

However, for general overload resolution, the conversion from `unsigned` to `float` is equivalent to the conversion from `float` to `unsigned`. So for instance in the following code snippet:

```
unsigned add(unsigned l, unsigned r) { return l + r;  }
float add(float l, float r) { return l + r;  }

int main()
{
    unsigned ui = 1;
    float fval = 2.5;
    add(ui, fval);
}
```

It's unable to decide which version of `add` to use and fails to compile.